# Function sequence error with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, alteryx

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server. Whenever I try to call it using the Alteryx Input tool, I get the following error:

> Error: Dynamic Input (56): Error SQLExtendedFetch: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error

Stored procedure code:

```
USE [DevSaqib]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTryCatch]    
AS         
BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY
        PRINT 'test'

        SELECT 'Return Value' = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'test failed'
        SELECT 'Return Value' = -1
    END CATCH
END -- proc end
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove the `PRINT` statements?

Comment: Saw this and it looked similar. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/86fc9d29-99ee-416e-891f-2451c4f09f4d/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-function-sequence-error-in-64bit-windows-2008-server?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: The issue isn’t the procedure. That’s is to say its syntax is correct. This is an odd procedure though. I can’t envision its purpose